# DBMS output not showing results

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using a script to attempt to find what column a value exists in. I'm a complete Oracle novice, but there isn't anyone else to do it.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE 

    CURSOR cur_tables 
    IS 
    SELECT table_name, 
           column_name 
    FROM   user_tab_columns
    WHERE  data_type = 'VARCHAR2';

    v_sql         VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_value       VARCHAR2(50);
    v_count       NUMBER;

BEGIN
    
    v_value := 'Orange';

    FOR c_tables IN cur_tables LOOP
        v_sql := 'SELECT count(1) FROM ' ||  c_tables.table_name || ' WHERE ' || c_tables.column_name || ' = :val' ;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO v_count USING v_value;
        dbms_output.put_line(v_count);
        IF v_count > 0 THEN
           dbms_output.put_line('Table Name ' ||  c_tables.table_name || ' Column Name ' || c_tables.column_name || ' Row Count ' || v_count);
        ELSE
           dbms_output.put_line('Nothing found');
        END IF; 
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I have used this query, there is certainly a value called "Orange" as I can do a select statement on the field and retrieve it. However I have done the DBMS Output steps of "View>DBMS Output" and then done a new connection in DBMS Output with the Green Plus, I have selected the database I am using in question and while I receive

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

For the query, I don't get any output in the DBMS Output, I have even added a basic put_line based on v_count to do it outside of the IF statement and nothing.

What can I try next?

Comment: If you're running as a script you should it in the script output window too. What happens if you add a debug outside the `for` loop? I suspect you don't own the table you're querying - if you run the cursor query yourself does it return anything, or do you need to query `all_tab_columns` to see the table you know has 'Orange' in it?

Comment: This is working for me. Are you by any chance using a really old version of Oracle say version 10 or 11?

Comment: @AlexPoole spot on its working but failing on the FOR then. This is a hosted DB we are not in control of. The cursor is being ran on "user_tab_columns" but that is empty which I assume is the issue? I've ran it on all_tab_columns but can't find the value however I know 100% it exists in the tables.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I am right in thinking that this query should spit out to me the column that the value "Orange" is found in and what table? right?

Comment: I didn't test your code for logic, only to make sure the serveroutput and DBMS_OUTPUT bits were working as expected in Oracle SQL Developer - they are or should be.

Comment: Start by looking at the table you know has the values - get the owner, table name, column name and data type from `all_tab_columns` for that, and run your cursor query just for the owner/table to see what you get back. Maybe it's CHAR not VARCHAR2 (see [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/Qnq_LR0T) vs [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/XsS4iIx4))?